# when does model diverged? and what is the next step

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, resnet

I'm using the detectron2 with cascade rcnn.
I'm predicting 4 different classes. and dataset with around 6000 object boxes with training.
I used resnet 50 for backbone and got around 80 accuracy.
then I try it with resnet 101 back bone and it diverged with first iteration.

```
1. small dataset and big model easily diverged at the first iteration?
2. what heppen to small dataset and big back bone
3. And for my case augmentation + resnet50 backbone decrease the result why?
4. How should I fix this diverged problem?(what is the step next)
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the [detectron2 model zoo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/MODEL_ZOO.md#other-settings) for Cascade R-CNN, their pre-trained models only use ResNet50 as backbone ([config 1](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/configs/Misc/cascade_mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x.yaml) and [config 2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/configs/Misc/cascade_mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml)).

So the most likely reason your model diverges is that most of the parameters will need to be trained from scratch (which is much more difficult and will require more data) as there is no pre-trained ResNet101.

Please also note that using a larger model increases the risk of overfitting.